# How to connect React frontend to Node api on cloud/online?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, heroku

Sorry in advance for my lengthy post.

I am having difficulty changing from MERN localhost to an online hosting. I've been hosting my frontend/ client side website on heroku, with the file structure as follows:

**Client Structure**

```
- build
- src
  - App.js
  - Index.js
  - Other Components, Images, Fonts, Pages
-package.json
-package-lock.json
```

This file structure works fine with heroku.

However, I've been following a Youtube tutorial that uses a MERN stack to build a blog: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OML9f6LXUUs&t=3s --> it is a 3 part series

In the video, he has a file structure as such:

**API and Client Structure**

```
- api
  - images
  - models
  - public
  - routes
  - index.js
  - package.json
  - package-lock.json

- client (frontend code)
  - build
  - src
    - App.js
    - Index.js
    - Other Components, Images, Fonts, Pages
  -package.json
  -package-lock.json
```

**2 Instances of LocalHost**

He runs api on localhost:3001 and client on localhost:3000.

**Methodology**

*1. Storing Images*

He does not store images in MongoDB cloud, but rather store the image name only, and stores the images directly on the api/images directory.

In the api folder, he uses multer to store the images.

```
app.use("/images", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "/images")))

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (request, file, callback) => {
      callback(null, 'images');
    }, 
    filename: (request, file ,callback) => {
      callback(null, request.body.name);
    },
  })

  const upload = multer({storage: storage});
  app.post('/api/upload', upload.single('file'), (request, response) => {
    response.status(200).json('File has been uploaded');
  });
```

Then in the client side, he sends the data via axios:

```
const response = await axios.post('/upload', data);
```

*2. Retrieving Images*

When retrieving, he specifies a public folder PF, uses axios to get the image name, and then concatenates them to get the images.

```
const PF = "http://localhost:3001/images/";
<Image src={PF + post.image} />
```

My question is:

1. How can I change from a localhost to a cloud based hosting (preferably Heroku)? What paths do I specify? I would think that this image retrieval works because I am running both locally on the same computer. I wouldn't be able to use it if they are online as the image src directory will not be searchable
2. Is it possible to host both simultaneously on 1 Heroku Dyno, and how can I do it?

This is my first time learning backend so thanks for the patience!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you'll have to remove all hardcoded 'http://localhost:3000`. This would interfere with the cloud site since it uses its own.

Instead, you could use an environment file to store the API site and in production use a different one.

You will need to make a mongodb cluster (its a cloud database and its free) https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/tutorial/create-new-cluster/. You'll have to manually change your database to the cluster link. I would use an environment variable for this as well, so the db link would be something like this in your db file

```
const mongoURI = process.env.MONGODB_URI || 'mongodb://localhost:27017/ProjectAPI'
```

where process.env.mongodb_uri contains cluster uri

In the server file where you host your routes add this to the end of your file and change to match your app:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/../client/build"));


app.get("*", (req, res) => {
  // check for page routes that we expect in the frontend to provide correct status code.
  const goodPageRoutes = ["/", "/login", "/home"];
  if (!goodPageRoutes.includes(req.url)) {
    // if url not in expected page routes, set status to 404.
    res.status(404);
  }

  // send index.html
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/../client/build/index.html");
});
```

After that just follow the guide: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git and https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-nodejs